# Can anyone make sense of this unexpected value error from scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), [shape=(M, N)])?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, artificial-intelligence

When using scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), [shape=(M, N)]) I get the value  error: data, indices, and indptr should be rank 1. BUT the data indices and indptr I am using are rank 1 and I have confirmed this with numpy.linalg.matrix_rank() which returns rank 1 for each of the matrices … does anyone have any idea what may be causing this error and/or where to look?

the way I'm calling scipy.sparse.csr_matrix is:

```
initCSR = sps.csr_matrix(( np.ones((self.N*self.T,1)), ex_s_reshaped, po), shape=(self.mdp_data['states'],self.T*self.N))
```

the rank and shape of variables are:

```
np.ones((self.N*self.T,1)) rank: 1 and shape (8000, 1)

ex_s_reshaped rank: 1 and shape (8000, 1)

po rank: 1 and shape (1, 8000)

Shape = (4, 8000)
```

The error message I get is:

[image]

Since data, indices and indptr I am using have rank 1, and their shapes seems sensible ... I just can't see where this value error is coming from!

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Are you on an old version of scipy? It seems to me where it says rank 1 what is meant is 1D. You could try and squeeze you inputs.

Comment: 1) If you switch to Python3 (not hard for small scripts, and there are tools to help) it will be easier to get help, and can solve a lot of bugs, maybe including this one. 2) Please post stack traces as text, not image.

Comment: Shapes are wrong, they should be 1d, (8000,) etc.  Trying to create a `csr` with the 3 compressed format arrays is tricky unless you know what you are doing.  The `indptr` array should have one more value than the number of rows.  You don't show the values or how they are created, but I suspect they really are the `coo` style, `data`, `row`, `col`.  If so you have the argument () wrong.  Step back and practice making a few small matrices and reread the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rank 1 arrays are arrays of shape `(m, )`, the arrays of shape `(m, 1)` are commonly known as vectors. To make your numpy arrays rank-1 array, use `ravel` method. You can read the doc [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html). Usage is as follows

```
vector = np.random.randn(100,1) # vector.shape = (100, 1)
rank_1_array = vector.ravel() # rank_1_array.shape = (100, )
```